# TableView items are not removed but do not respond

Tags: java, netbeans, javafx, tableview, javafx-8

Firstly, I am working on Windows 7, Netbeans 8, JDK 8.
I have a `TableView` containing `POJO` objects (not using properties).
I am trying to implement "*search while typing*" but something strange happens.
In this image you can see that ALL the students are being displayed:
[image: all students displayed]

In the next picture after the search is done you can see the problem. 
First 4 students are the actual search results and are clickable active entries in the `TableView`.
All the others entries are visible but not responding, but instead they should have been removed completely.
[image: problematic search results]

**How it works** **(coding part)**:
 1. When users types 'f' a function is called.
 2. In the function I create new list that will contain the search results:
`ObservableList<Student> subentries = FXCollections.observableArrayList();`
 3. Then I add all items matching the criteria of the search in `subentries` list
 4. I call:
 5. `studentsTable.setItems(subentries);`
Erroneous result is shown in picture 2.
**HACKS I tried:**
1. `randomButton.fire();`
2.

```
columnsOfTheTable.get(0).setVisible(false);
columnsOfTheTable.get(0).setVisible(true);
```

The above don't work.
Any help would be appreciated.
Thanks

Comment: Are you using any custom cell factories?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is a bit of a guess, but if you are using custom cells (or rows) in your table, make sure their `updateItem(...)` methods properly handle empty cells:

```
@Override
public void updateItem(SomeType item, boolean empty) {
    super.updateItem(item, boolean);
    if (empty) {
        setText(null);
        setGraphic(null);
    } else {
        // configure cell...
    }
}
```

Comment: YOU are the man, thanks. 
My mind didn't go there at all because of all the questions here in SO about refreshing items in `TableView`