# JavaFX - Cannot Refresh/Update ListView

Tags: java, listview, javafx, removing-whitespace

Well it appears I have been stumped by one of the simplest ListView implementations out there. For a few days I have found it impossible to properly reallocate a JavaFX ListView. I am working on making an EntityView completely dynamic, being able to remove elements whenever needed through a ContextMenu. So I have a ListView that is populated by an ArrayList, which we will refer to as "renderable". When you select "Remove" in the context menu, it removes the Entity from the renderable list, which also happens to be the "value" of the List Cell on whom I right clicked. Afterwards, I wish to refresh the ListView and remove now the nonexistent cell. So by creating a new ObservableList with the new renderable list (which removes the correct entity and that works fine), I set the items in the ListView, which does jack shit. I can set the list to null in this case, which removes all the elements. But I cannot reset the list with the new array and it remove the now missing entity. Somebody point me in the right direction please!

[image: This is the EntityView list]

When I use the method I stated above, it removes it from the list, but not visually. There becomes an unusable cell at the bottom of the list, which has its name.

[image: Here is a picture of the engine]

```
public void createContextMenu(final Entity curr, MouseEvent me){
    MenuItem[] items = {new MenuItem("EDIT TYPE"), new MenuItem("REMOVE")};

    ContextMenu menu = new ContextMenu(items);

    menu.show(list, me.getScreenX(), me.getScreenY());

    items[1].setOnAction(new EventHandler<ActionEvent>(){
        public void handle(ActionEvent arg0) {
            CanvasTab tab = (CanvasTab) core.canvasTabbedPane.getSelectionModel().getSelectedItem();
            Kanvas k = tab.canvas;

            k.renderable.remove(curr);
            System.out.println(k.renderable);

            k.redraw();

            EntityView.this.list.getItems().remove(curr);

            ObservableList<Entity> temp = FXCollections.observableList(k.renderable);
            EntityView.this.list.setItems(temp);
        }   
    });
}
```

This is the context menu:

[image]

Comment: Back your items in ObservableList instead of ArrayList. Setting this ObservableList to listview's items then removing the item from ObservableList is enough. It will reflected to listview items. Later can post some sample code if you want.

Comment: Are you using a custom cell factory?

Comment: possible duplicate of [TableView items are not removed but do not respond](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23180428/tableview-items-are-not-removed-but-do-not-respond) (I'm guessing, but I think this is your issue)

Comment: Please post your ListCell code for EntityView.this.list